# Java: single frame vs multiple frames

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, layout-manager

Think about the classic installation process, where you have a "next" button and when you click it the content of the window changes. To represent this situation I thought of two possible solutions:

-when "next" is clicked destroy the current JFrame and create a new JFrame, maybe passing to his constructor useful information (e.g. actual window size, content inserted by the user in the current frame, ...)

-when "next" is clicked remove all the components from the current JFrame and add new components as needed

The first solution looks way better about OOprogramming, because I can keep separate classes for different frames and I can avoid huge methods that empty the frame and repopulate it. However the first solution sounds a bit "dirty" and I should pass lots of parameters to the new frame. To represent this situation I would choose the second solution.

Now think about a menu with an "option" component: in this situation I would create a new JFrame when "option" is clicked, so that I can populate it with option items. Is this a correct solution? Is there a way I can always know which one is the best solution? Are there any solutions I didn't think about?

Comment: See also this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/230513).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Destroying the main `JFrame` would be silly -- not to mention jarring for the user. Just use a single `JFrame` and change its contents.

To implement an installer wizard, use a single `JFrame` containing one large `JPanel` on top and a smaller one containing the "Next", "Back", "Cancel" buttons along the bottom. When the `Next` or `Back` buttons are pressed, you replace the large `JPanel`. You can have many different `JPanel` subclasses, one for each "page" of the wizard.

There's a `LayoutManager` called `CardLayout` which is ideal for implementing this scenario -- it manages a "stack" of components, and only shows one of those components at a time. Use a `BorderLayout` in the `JFrame`. Into the center position put a `JPanel` with a `CardLayout`. Then add the individual pages of the wizard to that `JPanel`, so the `CardLayout` can manage them.

Comment: Thank you Ernest, your solution seems really good. Is there some situation in which is more suitable to create a new JFrame (maybe destroying the old one)? If the answer is yes, could you make me an example? And how am I supposed to choose between this two strategies?

Comment: Not really, I don't think that ever makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

The [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) is well suited for this.  You just swapout the JPanel contents when the "Next" button is pressed.